# duplicate symbol _utf8_decode Error Xcode5 for using two frameworks

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

Getting this strange error while compiling code in Xcode5:

```
duplicate symbol _utf8_decode in:
     /iOS Development/.../.../Framework/OpenEars.framework/OpenEars(OpenEars)
     /iOS Development/.../.../Framework/QZXLSReader.framework/QZXLSReader(xlstool.o)

ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am using XLS Parsing library & OpenEars Library in my project & imported both libraries.

One more question is: How to use `-v` in Xcode linking to see the verbose log.

Comment: Both of the libraries have a function with the same name.  You need to do something about that.

Comment: i386 instruction set is used only for simulator try on device if its still there then some issue